# QT Windows 7 helloworld program -> debug/main.o Error 1

Tags: qt, debugging, windows-7

I am trying to install and use QT framework on my Windows 7 Professional edition 32 bits machine. I downloaded whole pack (800+ mb) of QT and run installer.
AFter that I added to my system PATH two lines:
J:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin;
J:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin

After that I created empty project in QT with simple program, that QT created for me by itself. Applications -> QT gui application, "Use as default project location", Next, Next, Next.
And here is the code, that was created:

```
mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


main.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

After that I hit Run button on beneath get following error:

```
19:23:09: Running steps for project qldt...
19:23:09: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
19:23:09: Starting: "J:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
J:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'J:/Users/shidant2/Desktop/workspace/qldt/qldt-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\qldt -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\qldt\main.cpp
Makefile.Debug:357: recipe for target 'debug/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'J:/Users/shidant2/Desktop/workspace/qldt/qldt-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
19:23:30: The process "J:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qldt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

As I understand, there no problem with the code, but with compiler.
I tried to look for solution, but did not find anything useful..
I guess such serious framework as QT has not to live with such problem, espicially when it impacts the beginner experience. 
So, please, lets solve it here and now )

I found something interesting.

I tried to build everyhing withut QT:

I go to cmd and go there to folder:
cd J:/Users/shidant2/Desktop/workspace/qldt/qldt-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug

There I run this:

g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\qldt -I"............\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include" -I"............\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"............\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtGui" -I"............\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"............\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\qldt\main.cpp

Then I get my main.o !

And if I try to build main.o from QT Creator, it can not build this main.o.
Creator creates empty main.o, hangs some time without doing single thing
and after that it gives error as I posted in first message.

I suspect this can be something with permissions for QT in Windows 7.
But still can not figure out what is the problem.

Any suggestions, guys?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.qtforum.org/article/38999/error-compiling-wrong-slash-used-in-makefile-debug.html

Is there a problem with the slashes it is using?